# Why do hard disks use only one head at a time?

Tags: parallel, hard-drive

I just came across [this 2019 article](https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2019/09/hard-disk-geometry-microbenchmarking/) where the author uses microbenchmarks to map the layout of sectors on harddisks. One of the things discussed is that disks switch to different heads after reading a track or group of tracks. That made me wonder, why would disks need to switch heads at all, why not have all heads active at the same time and mux/demux the reads and writes in the controller. That would speed up the sequential disk speed by several times without much cost.

Comment: How do you know they don't? It is really  up to how manufacturers want their drives to work.

Comment: @Justme The linked article describes measuring access time differences in order to derive the physical layout of data on disks. It discusses the track layouts that different disks use. If heads would be reading at the same time that would be visible in the access times.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out the question was answered in the same article, just had to read it better. Tracks nowadays are so small that they aren't aligned accurately enough across platters for heads to read multiple platters at the same time:

> A cylinder is a collection of tracks on multiple surfaces that are located at the same radius (If a track is a circle, then a stack of circles of the same diameter forms a cylinder). On older drives, tracks on different surfaces were aligned so that accessing tracks within the same cylinder only required switching heads (a faster electrical operation) but not moving the heads (a slower mechanical operation). Cylinders are no longer meaningful on modern drives. With increased track density, tracks on different recording surfaces aren’t aligned well enough to form cylinders and a head switch requires a larger head movement than moving to an adjacent track on the same surface, which makes a head switch slower than moving to an adjacent track.

That leaves the question of why heads weren't active at the same time back when tracks still formed proper cylinders, but depending on when that was, I can imagine several reasons.